# R: dim(X) must have a positive length (autoR in psych)

Tags: r, psych

I have time-series data for many subjects (Rid) and I'm using the psych package and try to run this code: `autoR(inertia$depression_sum, group = inertia$Rid, lag  = 1)`

But I get this error: `Error in apply(x[1:(n.obs - lag), ], 2, sd, na.rm = na.rm) :  dim(X) must have a positive length`

Btw, this code from same package works as intended with no error on the same data `mssd(instability$depression_sum, group = instability$Rid)`

Head of data:

```
> inertia %>% 
+     select(Rid,depression_sum) %>% 
+     head(., n= 40)
# A tibble: 40 x 2
# Groups:   Rid [2]
   Rid   depression_sum
   <chr>          <dbl>
 1 R323          105.  
 2 R323           65.4 
 3 R323          132.  
 4 R323          102.  
 5 R323           NA   
 6 R323           -1.52
 7 R323         -164.  
 8 R323          -78.5 
 9 R323           NA   
10 R323          203.  
# ... with 30 more rows
```

Comment: Are there any subjects for whom there is no more than one non-missing observation in the data set?

Comment: Every participant has several NA's (night lags).
Some participants have several consecutive NA's.